# Angular 6 application with i18n inside ts code

Tags: angular, internationalization, primeng

Im working on translating my angular application following this post
http://www.dzurico.com/i18n-with-angular-6/

im also using the primeng component library and im giving custom error messages according to the application flow
for example

```
if (duplicateSerial) {
      this.msgs.push({
        severity: 'error', summary: 'Serial already selected'
      });
      setTimeout(() => this.msgs = [], 2000);
      return;
    }
```

what is the approach to translate the literal inside the TS code 'Serial already selected'

Comment: Could you be more specific? What are you trying to translate to?

Comment: Refer this - https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56075872/4399281

Answer (score 4):

This is all a matter of which translation framework you prefer. with [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core), for example, the translation would look like this.

You have either somewhere a folder with i18n-json-files or you get the key value pairs directly from a database.

In case of files they're named by their location string like this

```
en.json, en-GB.json, en-US.json, de.json ...
```

And the content is a plain json-object consisting of key value pairs

```
{
    "wrong_password": "Wrong Password!",
    "serial_already_selected": "Serial Already Selected",
    "no_user_logged_in": "No User Logged In"
}
```

**App.Module**

Import your TranslateModule into AppModule and any other Module where you need the translation.

```
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

**Component**

Import the TranslateService in any component that needs translation

```
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

constructor(translate: TranslateService) {}
```

If you want to use it inside a components' ts file you do it this way:

```
if (duplicateSerial) {
  this.msgs.push({
    severity: 'error', summary: this.translate.instant('serial_already_selected')
  });
  setTimeout(() => this.msgs = [], 2000);
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private showInformationMessage() {
  this.messageService.add({
    severity: SeverityMessage.INFO,
    summary: (<HTMLInputElement>
        (document.getElementById('informationMessageSupplierVendorID'))).value,
    detail: ''
  });
}
```

then on any html code

```html
<input type="hidden"
       value="text to translate"
       i18n-value="text to translate|Label for information text to translate@@informationMessageToSupplierVendorID"
       id="informationMessageSupplierVendorID"/>
```